# where to put the unittest for library in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am a ruby and rails newbie. And I am working on a rails application with RadRails. RadRails has a "Switch to Test" function for my controller, model, etc. but not for my library. if I have class `Foo::Bar` in `/lib/foo/bar.rb`, where should I put the unittest for it?

or should I separate the foo library in a separated project?

Thanks.

Comment: at last, I choose to put it under `test/unit/lib/foo/bar_test.rb`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for RSpec framework we put lib tests in `spec/lib/`.

if you use Test::Unit framework you can try to put your tests in `test/lib/`, and, if that not works, you can just drop them into `test/unit/`.